# Exporting Bokeh Plots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, bokeh

Matplotlib when you invoke the show function, it will open a small python window and show the chart. How can I make Bokeh do the same? I don't want to save a file or open a browser windows. I want to to output like matplotlib. Why? Because I want to show its graphs inside Microsoft Power BI. So it has to produce some sort of image I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Bokeh's normal operation is to generate web content, i.e. HTML+JS that can drive interactive visualizations in the browser. Doing that is explicitly the main reason it was created. However, it is possible to [export Bokeh plots as PNG files](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/export.html#png-generation):

```
from bokeh.io import export_png

export_png(plot, filename="plot.png")
```

Note that this will save a file to disk, not open any sort of application window. There is nothing built into Bokeh to auto-open except Bokeh HTML output to browsers.